# Random displaying with equal distribution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to perform an experiment in which i have to serve my participants three possibilities (Positive Neutral and Negative: these are basically classes that will load in an html page) and are randomized as you can see below

```
function EqualDistribute(id) {
   var a;
   var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); //number between 1 and 10

   if (random <= 3) {
      a = '2';
      //load a neutral class 
   }
   if (random > 3 && random <= 6) {
      a = '3';
      //load a positive class
   }
   if (random > 6) {
      a = '4';
      //load a negative class
   }
   return false;
}
```

the value of 'a' changes with each class loaded - anyways, Now what i want to do is
- Randomize appearance of the classes (based on mathrandom or something else which im already doing, just so the appearance of the classes is random) And..
- Equal distribution of the classes (meaning at the end of experiment all the subjects get to see/experience equal number of classes loaded i.e. 
in my case 30 positive 30 negative and 30 neutral)

what im doing right now is simply randomly displaying the classes without keeping a balance of 30 each.

pardon my programming skills
and thanks in advance for help as im stuck withthis here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you do drawing with putting back. But you have to draw from a pool without putting back.

So your pool are all classes (30 negativ, 30 neutral and 30 positiv). After you select one, this type should be one less (not putting back).

```
var pool = [];
var count_per_class = 30;
var number_of_classes = 3;

// fill pool
for (var number = 0; number < number_of_classes; number++)
{
   for (var count = 0; count < count_per_class; count++)
   {
      pool.push(number);
   }
}

// returns a random class ID between 0 and number_of_classes - 1
function getNextClassId() {

   // get random index
   var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * pool.length));
   var class_number = pool[randomIndex];

   // remove item at index
   var start = pool.slice(0, randomIndex);
   var end = pool.slice(randomIndex + 1, pool.length);
   pool = start.concat(end);

   return class_number;
}

// test if it works
var testArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < number_of_classes; i++) {
   testArray[i] = 0;
}

// take out while classes remain in pool
while (pool.length > 0) {

   // Do something here with this ID, e.g. count occurrences for every class 
   // should be count_per_class at the end for each index.
   testArray[getNextClassId()]++;

}

// prints [30, 30, 30]
console.log(testArray);
```

Comment: thanks, can you please show me javascript code, thanks again

Comment: hi thanks for your reply - please have a look am using fischer shuffle algo and trying to find the first element in the array and then perform its countdown - im able to load CSS classes w.r.t their appearance but cannot do arr.shift() and even counter isnt working **bold** [link] https://jsfiddle.net/x4urk8qp/

Comment: The if-condition before `arr.shift()` is never true, because your reinitialize the variable m/n/l. And try adding `<input type="button" onClick="Myfunction()" value="Next">` to add a button that calls `MyFunction` again.

Comment: thank you very much for your kind reply - so, what should i do with declaring these variables as even making them global is not solving the problem

Comment: can you please also suggest for the Myfunction() as well because it has to be running onload and not by pressing a button , thanks alot

Comment: Make them global and call `shuffle` at the start of `MyFunction`. Otherwise you just get three times in a row the same  `x[0]` in `MyFunction` before you call `arr.shift()`.

Comment: To show the next class, you have to call `MyFunction` again. When you want to do that is up to you (e.g. button click, timeout etc.).

Comment: thanks again, but its not working even after that, please have a look https://jsfiddle.net/x4urk8qp/

Comment: thanks a lot your suggestions helped to come up with my own solution

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check if the class == 30, then you exclude your class from random distributions. So only last two classes are "participating". And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test on reload, you will probaly have to use `localStorage`.

Check out this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/BwzXmK)** and try refreshing the page.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot - however, in your solution even after reaching 30 it still loads the class - in my case its a CSS class and it should not be displayed on page or in fact loaded as once it has loaded 30 times, the function should exclude it from the 3 CSS classes and should run between the remaining two until one of them afterwards reaches 30 then the last one keeps loading and display to the participant, so that the CSS classes only loads 30 times each - I hope im making sense ?!

Comment: thanks a lot - your suggestions helped a lot to come up with my own solution :)